# Rails INNER JOIN expecting field "id" that does not yet exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Short Version:  I need to use a custom inner join to find the id in one table where two fields match in both tables in Rails, but Rails inner join makes assumptions about the relationship that I do not know how to work around.

Long Version:  I have taken over a Rails project which had a non-normalized database.  I pulled out some of the information into a new table and now I need to go through each entry and put a foreign key on the original table but I am having trouble coming up with the correct ActiveRecord query to grab the information.

In this scenario, a collection belongs to a repository and repositories may have many collections.

The project originally had all collections and repositories stored in the same table, with a NULL for collection name if it was a repository and with both repository name and collection name if it was a collection.  I created a migration that took all the unique repository names and stuck them in a repositories table.  Now what I need to do is go back through the collections table and add the id from the matching repository based on the string repname.

I have a query in SQL that pull the correct data:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT r.id, r.repname FROM collections c, repositories r WHERE c.repname = r.repname")
```

I am having trouble interacting with that object, however (getting errors like "undefined method 'last' for # Mysql2::Result..."), and I would prefer that I knew that everything was set up correctly in the Rails models.

When I try this I get an error:

```
Repository.joins(:collections).where("collections.repname = repositories.repname")
Repository Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories` INNER JOIN `collections` 
ON `collections`.`repository_id` = `repositories`.`id` WHERE (collections.repname = repositories.repname)

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'collections.repository_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories` INNER JOIN `collections` ON `collections`.`repository_id` = `repositories`.`id` WHERE (collections.repname = repositories.repname)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'collections.repository_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories` INNER JOIN `collections` ON `collections`.`repository_id` = `repositories`.`id` WHERE (collections.repname = repositories.repname)
```

I am new to both Rails and SQL so I think my problem may actually be in how I have set up the models.  I was using the database's existing naming conventions...maybe I should switch to the Rails repository_id convention, instead?

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :archive_object_collections, :foreign_key => :collid, :primary_key => :collid
  has_many :archive_object, :through => :archive_object_collections
  belongs_to :repository, :foreign_key => "repid"
end

class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
end
```

I fear that switching to repository_id would not fix the problem, however, as there is not an id of any kind on the collections table, yet.  That is why I need to run this query, so I can find and insert that information in as a foreign key on the collections table.  I have tried the inner join query without the foreign_key in the Collections class with no change.

Sorry for the long and winding question.  Does anybody have any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to iterate through the collections and repositories table and manually match it up.  This is what I ended up doing:

```
class AddForeignKeyToColl < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # Add a repid to the collections
    add_column :collections, :repository_id, :integer

    # Need to go through all of the repositories
    # and match their name against the repname of the collections
    # Then, if they match, add the repository id to the collection as repid
    repos = Repository.all
    colls = Collection.all
    repos.each do |repo|
      rname = repo.repname
      colls.each do |coll|
        if coll.repname == rname
          coll.update_attributes(:repository_id => repo.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

It seems to have worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define the foreign_key in repository model

```
class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, :primay_key => 'somekey',  :foreign_key => 'repid'
end
```

And then you can run a simple join query to fetch a result based on your query.

```
Repository.select('repositories.*, collections.*').where("repositories.col1 = ? AND collections.col2 = ?", val1, val2)
```

Otherwise if you want to get rid of these kinds of key definition then better start using rails convention. Define foreign key as **model_id**. In that case you don't have to define key names.

Comment: Thanks for the foreign_key advice!  That got me closer.  When I try your query it creats the following SQL:
SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories`  WHERE (repositories.repname = 'First Church of Christ, Scientist, Boston, MA' AND collections.repname = 'First Church of Christ, Scientist, Boston, MA')

Since collections is not added to the "FROM" portion it errors.

I think the real issue is that my foreign key is currently empty.  I need to populate it based on the results from something like 

SELECT r.id, r.repname FROM collections c, repositories r WHERE c.repname = r.repname

Comment: can you just post your query?

Comment: 2.1.3 :005 > Repository.where("repositories.repname = ? AND collections.repname = ?", val, val)
  Repository Load (2.9ms)  SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories`  WHERE (repositories.repname = 'First ...MA' AND collections.repname = 'First...MA')
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'collections.repname' in 'where clause': SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories`  WHERE (repositories.repname = 'First ...MA' AND collections.repname = 'First...MA')

Comment: I think I may have brainstormed a way to fix this.  If in a migration I iterate through all the repositories and then iterate through all of the collections, when I find a matching name I can insert the repository id as the foreign key for the collection.  It is messy but it should only have to get run once on production!

Comment: Do you have column name repname in your repositories table? Your error says there is no such column.

Comment: Yes I do.  I believe the error is saying that I don't have the column repname in collections, but that is because the query itself doesn't have FROM repositories, collections. If I run the SQL query with both of those in the FROM then it works.  I just don't know how to do that in Rails.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I had missed to select the col in my query. It has been modified now. Check if it works?

Comment: I figured out a way around my original question.  Thank you for helping me work this out and for posting the query.  Unfortunately, the latest query is trying to select both rather than search both tables:
SELECT repositories.*, collections.* FROM `repositories`  WHERE (repositories.repname = 'Boston Public Library, Boston, MA' AND collections.repname = 'Boston Public Library, Boston, MA')